Create service which instantiates a web-worker and starts an interval so that main thread can subscribe to it?
At my job I encountered a problem where a component needed to poll for some data, and as part of that process update the title of the page based on information returned from said data. We noticed that while the page was in an inactive tab, the title of the page was not updating at the speed of the interval (up to 5min when the interval is 30sec). This was because the execution of code in inactive tabs is throttled by the browser.
Looking into a way to solve for this, I found suggestions to use web-workers. Is there a way I can create a re-usable service that instantiates a worker which starts an interval so that the main thread can subscribe to it?
I tried using a library https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wbds/angular-web-worker and used the following:
The worker created with the library:
/// <reference lib="webworker" />

@AngularWebWorker()
export class MyWorker implements OnWorkerInit {
  @Subscribable()
  intervalHeartbeat: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor() {}

  onWorkerInit() {
    interval(1000*30).subscribe(() => this.intervalHeartbeat.next(true));
  }

}
bootstrapWorker(MyWorker);

The component using MyWorker:
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private myWorker: WorkerClient<MyWorker>;

  constructor(private someService: SomeService, private workerManager: WorkerManager) {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.someService.getInitialInfo().subscribe(info => this.info = info);
    this.initializeHeartbeat();
  }

  initializeHeartbeat() {
    this.myWorker = this.workerManager.createClient(MyWorker);
    this.myWorker.connect().then(() => {
      this.myWorker.observe(w => w.intervalHeartbeat)
        .then(heartbeat => heartbeat.subscribe(() => this.findTheInfoNeededFromPolling()));
    });
  }

  findTheInfoNeededFromPolling() {
    this.someService.findInfoById(this.currentId).subscribe(info => {
      this.info = info;
      this.updatePageTitleWithNewInfo();
    }
  }
}

The definitely seemed to work. It still throttled the execution of some things but the time went from up to 5min while in an inactive tab, down to 1-1.5min which we can live with. Unfortunately, this library is not being maintained, and with plans to upgrade our Angular version in the future, this will break. Hoping I can accomplish something similar on my own?
